Button is getting hidden in TimePicker of native Xamarin.Android in Landscape Mode
I have a Date & TimePicker in my solution which displays well on Portrait mode but when I change it to Landscape mode the "OK" button in TimePicker is getting hidden.
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(_activity);
 var name = _activity.GetString([![Resource.String.set_date][1]][1]);
 timePicker = new TimePicker(_activity);
 timePicker.SetIs24HourView(Java.Lang.Boolean.True);

 timePicker.TimeChanged += TimePicker_TimeChanged;
 
 builder.SetView(timePicker);
 builder.SetPositiveButton("OK", (sender, e) =>
 {
    OnTimeSet(true);
    UnlockOrientation(_activity);
 });

 builder.SetNegativeButton("Cancel", (sender, e) =>
 {
    _timedialog.Cancel();
     UnlockOrientation(_activity);
 });

 builder.SetNeutralButton(name, DateClickedEvent);   



Any help is appreciated!
